# Can't write the right htaccess file for a url redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I've read tons of other answers about this case but nothing helped. I have this website http://allutas.com with the following folder structure

```
Allutas
 Application 
   Controllers
      index.php
   Models
   Views
 System
 index.php
```

when you visit http://allutas.com the index page performs some checks and if everything is right it sends the user to Application/Controllers/index.php

and all the other pages that the user can visit are located in that Controllers folder too

so simply what I'm trying to do is to remove or hide the subdirectories part in my website from all the files in the controller folder along with the .php extension so instead of

http://allutas.com/Application/Controllers/index.php
or
http://allutas.com/Application/Controllers/about.php

I want it to be like that

http://allutas.com/index
or
http://allutas.com/about

I've tried a lot of other answers and they ended up doing nothing or cause a 500 internal server error

here's an example of an htaccess file that is gonna give a 500 internal server error

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On    
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$  application/controllers/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

If it helps, my host is using Apache version 2.4.3-25 and PHP version 5.6.27

Comment: `application` != `Application` check your case.

Comment: Though really you want to look into using a router to load the controllers. As you will have better control over invalid routes and be able to handle them accordingly.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried both upper and lower case nothing changs

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /Allutas/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Application/Controllers/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>
```

It should work for these type of links:
http://allutas.com/about.php
http://allutas.com/index.php

Comment: it causes 500 Internal Server Error any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**In the .htaccess file you:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> Goes to index. Sets a `$_GET['url']`  to whatever comes after the domain name of the site.

**In your *index.php* file (next to the *.htaccess* file):** you should be able to get the content of the `$_GET['url']` easily without any trouble!

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo $url;
```

**This is what you'll get:**

> Text1/Text2/Text3

**Commonly it's used like,**

1. text1 refers to a controller
2. text2 refers to an action
3. text3 refers to a params

Do whatever you want with it!